# ...waited until recently...[Is 'until recently' a complement of 'waited'?]

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, complements, adjuncts

This [article](http://www.politico.com/story/2017/07/17/scott-garrett-trump-export-import-bank-nominee-240639) says in part:

> Though the White House first announced his nomination in April, lobbyists **waited until recently** to begin publicly mounting an aggressive opposition effort.

Is 'until recently' here a complement of the verb 'waited' or simply an adjunct?
Also, what about "to begin publicly mounting an aggressive opposition effort"?

Comment: The infinitival clause complements **waited**. I would regard **until recently** as additional info, an adjunct.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo But in _they waited from last December until recently_, aren't both _from last December_ and _until recently_ complements of _waited_?

Comment: "They waited" is a well-formed clause. The prepositional phrases bring extra information to bear, but are not indispensable, and so they are adjuncts. Whereas with "He put a bandage on the wound.", "He put a bandage" is not a well-formed clause, "on the wound" being necessary to complete the idea of "put"; in that case the prepositional phrase is a complement.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence ***'until recently"*** is not a complement of ***"wait"***. It is a Temporal Adjunct [FUNCTION in the sentence], realized by a Preposition Phrase (PP).

The structure of this preposition Phrase (PP) is like this -

[image]

CORRECTION: Sorry for the mistake in the tree. There should not be (PP) beside Complement.

Comment: The complement of "until" is an Adverb Phrase consisting of (headed by) the adverb "recently". Note that it can be modified, e.g. "until very recently".